# How to bind this to a function for AngularIO's Observable::subscribe?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, this, subscribe

There are a lot of examples using the `Observable.subscribe()` function from AngularIO. Anyhow, I was only able to see anonymous functions inside as in:

```
bar().subscribe(data => this.data = data, ...);
```

If I try to hand in a function of the same class like here:

```
updateData(myData : DataType[]) {
   this.data = data;
}
...
bar().subscribe(this.updateData, ...);
```

Then the `this` object in line 2 doesn't refer to the current object anymore. This is probably some JavaScript logic that I don't understand. I know that you can bind an object to a function, is this what I have to do? Is this best practice? How would one usually resolve this issue (I'd like to avoid having a big anonymous function inside the `subscribe()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can wrap it inside an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which will capture the correct `this`:

```
bar().subscribe((myData) => this.updateData(myData), ...);
```

Or use [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) which will also bind the correct context:

```
bar().subscribe(this.updateData.bind(this), ...);
```

But be aware that `Function.bind` returns `any` which will make you lose type checking in TypeScript. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/212

Comment: You could also hide the messy details in a helper function using [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/call): 

`private subscribeBar(onDataChanged: (myData: any) => void): void {
  bar().subscribe((myData) => onDataChanged.call(this, myData));
}`

that you would call like this:

`this.subscribeBar(this.updateData);`

This is particularly useful if you also need to pass extra arguments or save the subscription(s) to unsubscribe at a later occasion, and to be able to assert properly in your unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the **fat arrow** behavior.

You can [find more here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html) (in the "this and fat arrow" topic, about half the page)